# Where can I find people to practice Scottish Gaelic with?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources

I'm learning Scottish Gaelic but without anyone to talk to and practice with it's tricky. Are there any free sites where I can chat to people in Scottish Gaelic to improve?

NOTE: Free is very preferable if not necessary.

Comment: When you say "free", does "freemium" count as well?

Comment: @AnthomPham it depends really. If it costs money to get started then I would say no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [italki](https://www.italki.com/partners?hl=en-us) is a resource that lists a few people who are fluent in Scottish Gaelic.
- [MyLanguageExchange](https://www.mylanguageexchange.com/Search.asp) is another online tool to help you connect with other Gaelic learners, and I found more than 20 users on that website learning Gaelic as well.
  You can also trying using this tool, [Conversation Exchange](https://www.mylanguageexchange.com/Search.asp), to find learners.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in distance-learning courses offered by certain Scottish universities, such as [Intensive Language Course: Gaelic Record of Achievement](https://www.dundee.ac.uk/short/gaelic-intensive) at the University of Dundee and [An Cùrsa Adhartais](http://www.smo.uhi.ac.uk/en/cursaichean/an-cursa-adhartais) at the University of the Highlands and Islands.

Answer (score 1):

Duolingo users organise ["events"](https://events.duolingo.com/) that in pre-pandemic times used to be meetings of people to socialise in the language they are learning. I can see that now most events are online and about one Scottish Gaelic event is scheduled per week.

Furthermore, any online community of Scottish Gaelic learners could be helpful to find other students to chat with. I'd suggest trying in [Duolingo forums](https://forum.duolingo.com/topic/969).

Disclaimer: I never tried attending to Duolingo events or finding a linguistic exchange there, so I can't tell about whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find a Scottish Gaelic language exchange partner, at least not if your native language is English. Take the time to master reading and listening first, then make a point to visit the Gaelic-speaking areas of Scotland. You can find lots of literature and listening materials online.